# Ensuring single-threadness of an object with Ring and Compojure

Tags: java, multithreading, clojure, compojure, ring

create-js-engine is an function that generates a ScriptEngine, an object that is not thread safe. I want to reuse from one request to the next but I never want to use one js-engine by more than one thread at the same time.

What's the appropriate way of doing this?

I tried this:

```
(defroutes routes
  (let [js-engine (create-js-engine)]
    (GET "*" request
      (render-app js-engine request))))
```

which effectively re-uses the same js-engine for consecutive requests within figwheel, but I'm not sure whether it would generate separate ones in other environments.

I almost feel like this should be a dynamic var, but I don't know when I should create the bindings as I'm not sure about the entry point for new threads and if I create the bindings around the route, then the simple let would work as well.

Comment: Can't you create a pool of js-engines ? When a thread needs a js-engine it would take it from the pool and when it's done with it it would return it back. This way you make sure that a single js-engine isn't used by more than a single thread.at the same time.

Comment: @ViktorK. as long as new js-engines are added on-demand, then, yes. How do I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a some idiomatic way for this in clojure (the use case itself is not very clojure friendly since you are using mutable object). You might look at [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and maybe wrap it with in your own class (or clojure function) that would create new js-engine in case that the queue is empty. This queue then might serve as the pool for your js-engines.

Comment: The question this is a duplicate of isn't specifically about js engines, but demonstrates how to get per-thread versions of something in the context of a webserver.